# Sets, subsets and Cartesian product.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, education, computational-mathematics, math-software

I am studying computer science and I have Maths exam soon. While solving past exam papers, I encountered with a sets question and couldn't solve. It consists of two parts (a) and (b) and couldn't solve part b but I am going to include all parts as it is required in order to solve the question.

Question is as follows:

(a) Let D be the set of decimal digits, `D = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`, and let E and L be the following subsets of D:

```
   E = { n ∈ D : n/2 ∈ D}  ,     L = {n ∈ D : n < 3}
```

Express the following sets as explicit lists of members, treating D is the Universal Set:

(i)   E ⋃ L

(ii)  E' ⋂ L

(iii) E x L

(b) The members of the Cartesian product D x D can be paired with members of the set `C = {0,1, ... ,99}` in the following way:

`(i,j) ∈ D x D  pairs with  n = 10i + j ∈ C`

Subsets of D x D can be paired with subsets of C in the same way; for example

`L x D ⊂ D x D  pairs with  {n ∈ C : n < 30} ⊂ C`

Find expressions, in terms of D, E and L, for the subsets of D x D that pair with the following subsets 
 of C:

(i)  A = {0,2,4,6, ...,96,98}

(ii) B = {0,1,2,20,21,22}

As I said, I only couldn't solve part (b) so I only need answers for part (b).
Many thanks for all of the answers in advance.

Comment: You seem to have some problems here with notation.  `E = { n ∈ D : n/2 V D}`  What could you mean by this?  Do you perhaps mean $\{n\in D~:~n\mid 2\}$?  The elements of $D$ who are even integers?  Note the difference between $n/2$ and $n\mid 2$.  Or do you perhaps mean $\{n\in D~:~n/2\in D\}$?  The elements of $D$ who when divided by $2$ their result is also in $D$?  Those happen to agree for this specific example, but not for an example like $\{2,4\}$

Comment: It should be {n∈D : n/2∈D} . My bad, I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Consider (b) ii: the elements of $B = \{ 0,1,2,20,21,22 \}$ are generated from pairs $\{ (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2) \}$ according to the encoding: $(i,j) ∈ D \times D$ where $i,j \in L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B)(i):  Expressing $\{0,2,4,6,8,10,\dots,96,98\}$ using the available sets.

The idea here is that the unnamed pairing function will take the first entry of the tuple and use that as the tens-digit and the second entry of the tuple and use that as the ones-digit.  Notice here that the tens-digit in what we want to express can range over all possible digits while the ones-digit ranges only over the even digits.

$$D\times E = \{(0,0),(0,2),(0,4),\dots,(9,6),(9,8)\}$$

which via the pairing function alluded to mapping $(a,b)\mapsto 10a+b$ gives the desired result

B)(ii):  Expressing $\{0,1,2,20,21,22\}$

The idea here is that the tens digit must be even and must be small while the ones-digit simply needs to be small.  We can ensure even-ness using $E$.  We can ensure small-ness using $L$.

$$(E\cap L)\times L = \{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)\}$$

which via the pairing function alluded to before mapping $(a,b)\mapsto 10a+b$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped a lot.